# Can I get an @ubuntu.com email address for the Ubuntu-related event I'm organising?

Tags: ubuntu-email-address

I'm currently organising an [unconference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconference) that will have a significant part of it's schedule given over to the ways in which people can contribute to Ubuntu, along with some workshops on topics like packaging, ISO testing and app development. This event has run for several years now and we imagine it running for many more, and I was wondering if it would be possible to get `<myevent>@ubuntu.com` as an email address for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two routes for this:

1. - Change your launchpad username to that of the conference (or create a new launchpad membership, if that's allowed)
   - Apply for and then gain membership under that username.

   It's slow and not guaranteed if you don't already have membership.
2. Email rt@ubuntu.com and plead your case.

   It should be possible and if you're already a member or doing things worthy of membership (which it sounds like it's a given) they should be able to help you. rt@ is the alias for their internal ticket handler (Request Tracker).

Answer (score 3):

**Ubuntu Email**

The right to have an Ubuntu email address alias (@ubuntu.com) is a privilege that all members (direct/indirect) of the Ubuntu members team on Launchpad possess. For information about Ubuntu membership, see [Membership](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership).

The address is taken from your Launchpad username so will be: launchpad_username@ubuntu.com , email sent to this address will be forwarded to your main email address set on Launchpad.

A similar service exists for Kubuntu members and Edubuntu members (@kubuntu.org and @edubuntu.org respectively).

There is more information [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuEmail).

To obtain an @ubuntu.com email address you need to apply to become an [Ubuntu Member](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership) and be approved.  To be approved you will need to be able to show that you have made a significant contribution to ubuntu.

Full details on membership requirements and application procedure are given [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Membership)

Answer (score 0):

@ChrisWilson, I don't think so.

@ubuntu.com email address are specially suited for personal Ubuntu members for their award of contributing substantively and prolongly to Ubuntu. I have never seen a event getting a @ubuntu.com address.

You should rather get your own @ubuntuunconference.com or that sort of thing. Maybe set up a mailing list for your unconference will be better. That way, people can communicate within the mailing list. Just write a request to the Request Tracker (however a friendly reminder: Canonical IS may get to your request months later).