# I would like to delete an accidental post I did on paste.ubuntu.com while using Bootrepair

Tags: boot-repair, privacy, pastebin

I wanted to find out were the MBR physically is (I have a multiboot PC with several HD) and Bootrepair has done its job.

I then discovered that beyond my control private information was send to http://paste.ubuntu.com. I really would like to delete that post with my data (And I think that before sending information on the internet a confirmation request would be clever and smart. Don't you?).

So, please: Is there any simple way to delete or edit a page like http://paste.ubuntu.com/xxxxxx?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you can email rt@ubuntu.com and ask them to remove the post, but don't expect a quick removal. *rt@ is the alias for their internal ticket handler (Request Tracker).*<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup><sub>Source: Answer to the question [Can I get an @ubuntu.com email address for the Ubuntu-related event I'm organising?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272980/can-i-get-an-ubuntu-com-email-address-for-the-ubuntu-related-event-im-organisi/273012#273012) by Oli</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can neither delete nor edit any pages on [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com) yourself. The only way to remain fairly safe is to remove the links of the page you have pasted the contents to.

<sub>Source:</sub>

[How to remove a page on paste.ubuntu.com](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2144024)