# How do I report spam on ubuntu websites like paste.ubuntu.com

Tags: bug-reporting

As @Lucio reported on chat, there are spam on [paste.ubuntu.com](http://paste.ubuntu.com/). I wanted to report them, but i saw no `report spam` button?

Quetsion in a nutshell, How can I report spam on paste.ubuntu.com, and other official Ubuntu websites.

- http://paste.ubuntu.com/8742111 <sup>Now Deleted</sup>
- http://paste.ubuntu.com/8742112 <sup>Now Deleted</sup>
- http://paste.ubuntu.com/8742116 <sup>Now Deleted</sup>
- http://paste.ubuntu.com/8742117 <sup>Now Deleted</sup>
- http://paste.ubuntu.com/8742118 <sup>Now Deleted</sup>

For anyone interested:

> ```
> Greetings,
>
> This message has been automatically generated in response to the
> creation of a trouble ticket regarding:
>   "Spam on paste.ubuntu.com", 
> a summary of which appears below.
>
> There is no need to reply to this message right now.  Your ticket has been
> assigned an ID of [rt.ubuntu.com #25687].
>
> Please include the string:
>
>          [rt.ubuntu.com #25687]
>
> in the subject line of all future correspondence about this issue. To do so, 
> you may reply to this message.
>
> Thank you,
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to mail `rt@ubuntu.com` (rt@ is the alias for their internal ticket handler (Request Tracker)).

Source: [Can I get an @ubuntu.com email address for the Ubuntu-related event I'm organising?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272980/can-i-get-an-ubuntu-com-email-address-for-the-ubuntu-related-event-im-organisi/273012#273012)